# Why latest version of sys-stat not showing average values after kill..?

Tags: linux, memory, profiling, cpu, cpu-usage

The old output from my logs which showing Avg values after ctrl+c

```
#pidstat 1 -p `pgrep bgpd`
Linux 3.16.7-gd1a374d-dellz9100on (rtr1)        Tuesday 29 May 2018     _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

05:07:01  UTC   UID       PID    %usr %system  %guest    %CPU   CPU  Command

05:07:07  UTC     0      2144    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     2  bgpd
05:07:08  UTC     0      2144    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     2  bgpd
05:07:09  UTC     0      2144    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     2  bgpd
05:07:10  UTC     0      2144    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     2  bgpd
05:07:11  UTC     0      2144    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     2  bgpd
05:07:12  UTC     0      2144    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     2  bgpd
^C
Average:        0      2144    0.09    0.00    0.00    0.09     -  bgpd
```

Now it is not showing Avg values

```
# pidstat 1 -p `pgrep bgpd`
    Linux 3.16.7-gd1a374d-dellz9100on (rtr1)        06/13/18        _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

    07:32:51          PID    %usr %system  %guest    %CPU   CPU  Command
    07:32:56         2144    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     0  bgpd
    07:32:57         2144    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     1  bgpd
    07:32:58         2144    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     1  bgpd
    ^C
 #
```

Version of pidstat

```
root@rtr1:/home/ocnos# pidstat -V
sysstat version 10.0.5
(C) Sebastien Godard (sysstat <at> orange.fr)
root@rtr1:/home/ocnos#
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately questions like these are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Oveflow, and therefore should be asked here:
[SuperUser](https://superuser.com) ot here: [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

The mail reply from Developer of this tools

```
No, your previous version was not 9.x. 
This feature (displaying average stats when Ctrl/C is hit) was added to pidstat in release 10.1.4.
Regards,
Sebastien.
```